# Replace the last comma in a string using Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string like:
    `"item 1, item 2, item 3"`.
What I need is to transform it to:
    `"item 1, item 2 and item 3"`.

In fact, replace the last comma with " and". Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use greediness to achieve this:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(.*),/','$1 and',$text)
```

This matches everything to the last comma and replaces it through itself w/o the comma.

Comment: can u explaing wat that $1 ll do... i waiting for ur answer

Comment: In regexes you can save parts of the matched string in so-called back references. You define a back reference by putting braces around a part of the expression. You can refer to the references by $1 to $9 or by \1 to \9. So $1 is the value of the first back reference, (.*) in this case.

Answer (score 13):

You can use this regex: `,([^,]*)$`, it matches the last comma and text after it.

```
$re = '/,([^,]*)$/m';
$str = 'item 1, item 2, item 3';
$subst = " and $1";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

No capture groups are necessary.  Just greedily match all characters in the string, then just before matching the last comma in the string, use `\K` to "forget" all previously matched characters.  This effectively matches only the last occurring comma.  Replace that comma with a space then the word "and".

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ngRBD))

```
echo preg_replace('/.*\K,/', ' and', 'item 1, item 2, item 3');
// item 1, item 2 and item 3
```