# Regex replacing part of string comma

Tags: javascript, regex, jqplot

So I have a string called 'str' (I'm using JQPlot so bare with the variable name).

The format of str is 'Date, Time, PointValue' so an example of this is:

`12/12/2015, 14:07, 7.894`

I am having rounding issues with the pointValue on JQPlot so I am using `tooltipFormatString: " %.2f"` in highlighter to round all values to two decimals. This however, impacts on the entire 'str' variable and messes up the date and time part of the string. An example would be: `124123231774.00, 7.89` - which is obviously good for the PointValue, but not for the date/time.

So I am trying to write a Regex expression that will only format the data after the last comma. So it would ignore date and time, but then would format the PointValue with '%.2f' so it is rounded to two decimals.

I have looked at the following: 
[regex to remove multiple comma and spaces from string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245897/regex-to-remove-multiple-comma-and-spaces-from-string-in-javascript)
[Replace the last comma in a string using Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705509/replace-the-last-comma-in-a-string-using-regular-expression)

And I am still stuck so any help and an explanation would be greatly appreciated. I have something like this at the moment which obviously doesn't work.

```
            function tooltipContentEditor(str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot) {
            str = str.replace(Expression Here);

            return "<span style='color:black;'><font style ='font-weight:900;'>" + plot.legend.labels[seriesIndex] + "</font><br>" + str + "</span>";
        };
```

Edit: The reason as to why I am needing this is because there are issues when I add more data series to the chart, that some of the Point Values that are grabbed from the server, become rounded and don't display the true value. So I am trying to format the value rather than letting it infer itself from the server. Ie it would round '7.899' to '8'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\d\.\d+$/` , `Number` , `.toFixed()`

```js
var str = "12/12/2015, 14:07, 7.894";
var res = str.replace(/\d\.\d+$/, function(match) {
  return Number(match).toFixed(2)
});
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I changed the 'res' variable to 'str' and removed the 'str' variable you defined. Now yes, it does round it to two decimals correctly, however I'm still left with a date/time issue: It actually now displays in scientific notation:  `1.4566E+12, 8.14` - 8.14 being the Point Value. 

I also removed the tooltipFormatstring as well - any ideas on the date/time still?

Comment: @Nomm See updated post, escaped `.` character with `\.` at `RegExp` which should only match number at end of input string

Comment: Still producing the same issue as in my first comment. I'll try having a bit more of a play and see if I can fix the issue as well.

Comment: @Nomm _"Still producing the same issue as in my first comment."_ Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Making a JSFiddle does 'solve the problem'. Meaning that defining the variable 'str' like you have above, will only impact on the last digit in the string, however I now feel as if it might be a problem with the server itself or something else. I will do some more digging and post my findings.

Comment: I think I've made a mistake in the format of the string - yes it does format as 'Date, Time, Value' however after looking at Fiddler, It is like:
DateTime=2016-02-25T13:04:55.7300000Z  
Point Value=7.7565

I suspect this may have an impact on the regex.